# hetzner vswitch и пул ip /27

Tags: маршрутизация, proxmox, vlan

Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать. 
Настроил vswitch на хецнере, 3 ноды proxmox видят друг друга. 
Хецнер выдал пул белых ip /27 для id 4000. 167.233.xxx.xxx 
Как его подключить к нодам?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Для начала 
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

echo "1 vswitch" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables



#И сам конфиг 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo inet6 loopback


#начальный сетевой конфиг
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address 95.xxx.84.169/26
        gateway 95.xxx.84.129
        up route add -net 95.xxx.84.128 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 95.xxx.84.129 dev eno1

#vSwitch для кластера (те айпишники которые будут мигрировать с контейнерами между нодами)
auto eno1.4000
iface eno1.4000 inet static
        address 10.0.0.3/24
        mtu 1400
        up ip addr add 167.xxx.4.226/27 dev eno1.4000
        up ip rule add from 167.xxx.4.226 lookup vswitch
        up ip rule add to 167.xxx.4.226 lookup vswitch
        up ip route add default via 167.xxx.4.225 dev eno1.4000 table vswitch
        down ip addr del 167.xxx.4.226/27 dev eno1.4000
        down ip route del default via 167.xxx.4.225 dev eno1.4000 table vswitch
        down ip rule del to 167.xxx.4.226 lookup vswitch
        down ip rule del from 167.xxx.4.226 lookup vswitch

#CIDR для одной из нод
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 167.xxx.4.226/27
        bridge-ports eno1.4000
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        bridge-vlan-aware yes
        bridge-vids 2-4094
        mtu 1400
```

Дальше добавить остальные ноды в сеть vswitch и вбить похожий конфиг, cidr брать из свободных айпи.